Eliminate vertical space between lstlisting and quotation
I defined a new environment blocknote to do "block notes" to contain text that you ordinarily might put in footnotes, but instead put them in an indented "block" bracketed by little squares.  I based it on quotation since it seems to do pretty much what I wanted — I just added the little squares around it.  See the definition below.
From the minimal example:

The spacing around the first blocknote (that is, between it and normal text both before and after) is good.
The spacing around the first lstlisting (that is, between it and normal text both before and after) is also good.
However, there's too much space between the second lstlisting and second blocknote.  I guess it's because the spacing after lstlisting and before quotation are both there.

For case 3, I can fix it by inserting \vspace{-\bigskipamount} right before the \begin{blocknote}, but that seems like a hack.
Is there a better way to implement blocknote such that there's only one blank line when it follows a lstlisting but preserves all other spacing as in cases 1 and 2?
FYI: I want the indentation of the blocknote to match that of lstlisting (which it currently does).
\newlength{\lstleftmargin}
\setlength{\lstleftmargin}{.4in}

\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  abovecaptionskip=\medskipamount,
  aboveskip=\baselineskip,
  belowcaptionskip=0pt,
  belowskip=\baselineskip,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breaklines=true,
  keepspaces=true,
  keywordstyle=\lst@ifdisplaystyle\bfseries\fi\normalsize,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2,
  xleftmargin=\lstleftmargin
}

\newenvironment{blocknote}
  {\begin{quotation}\noindent$\blacksquare$}
  {$\square$\end{quotation}}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{blocknote}
\lipsum[1][4-6]
\end{blocknote}

\lipsum[1][7-11]

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf( "hello, world\n" );
}
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[2][1-3]

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf( "goodbye, world\n" );
}

\end{lstlisting}

% \vspace{-\bigskipamount}  % when uncommented, it fixes it, but seems like a hack
\begin{blocknote}
\lipsum[2][4-6]
\end{blocknote}

\end{document}

